# Winforms c# - Set all booleans to false?

Tags: c#, winforms, boolean

I have a few booleans declared in my form which are triggered by keypresses. Essentially, I want it so when an if statement is triggered, **all the boolean variables in my form to be false**. I have the following in an if statement;

```
//Spike contact
        if (pbPlayer.Right > pbSpike1.Left && pbPlayer.Right < pbSpike1.Right && pbPlayer.Bottom > pbSpike1.Top || pbPlayer.Left < pbSpike1.Right && pbPlayer.Left > pbSpike1.Left && pbPlayer.Bottom > pbSpike1.Top)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Gameover!");
            pbPlayer.Location = ReSpawn;
            timer1.Start();
            foreach (bool Movement in this.Controls)
            {
                Movement = false;
            }
        }
```

When I try setting movement to false it says it's not assignable because it's a foreach iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by *all booleans in my form*? Do you mean all `CheckBox` controls? or all boolean member variables?

Comment: They are declared boolean variables

Comment: Hmm, that's fairly nonsensical.  Move them into another little class, create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to assign value to your member variables explicitly and avoid using such automatic logic which is error-prone.

As an option you can use reflection to find them and then set their value.
Add `using System.Reflection;` and then using below code you can find all non-public boolean member fields and set them to `false`:

```
this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                         BindingFlags.Instance |
                         BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(bool))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(f =>
    {
        f.SetValue(this, false);
    });
```

Comment: Is this going in the if-statement because BindFlags is not identified in this context.

Comment: Don't forget to add `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: Looks like it did it. My movement bools are no longer continued on their own, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do, but you're misusing `foreach`.  The `foreach` statement works on arrays and collections.  The variable that represents the element of the collection, must have a type that matches every element of the collection.  You can't use foreach to filter the collection for properties that match the type you specify.

The things in `this.Controls` must all be derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.  A checkbox can be in that collection, but a variable of type `bool` can't, because a bool (a `System.Boolean` to be precise) is not derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.